# Setting multiple Datacontext

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, binding

I am trying to find out how to set correctly multiple `DataContexts` in XAML page. I have a basic collection that I create in code behind and set `ItemSource` Binding og `AutoCompleteBox` to it. At the same time, I have another `datacontext` to set `labelsDataSource` inside the grid. If I set this datacontext, the AutoCompleteBox’s itemsSource binding is lost. `AutoCompleteBox` is inside that grid. I do assign `DataContext` directly to the objetc this way:

```
MyAutoCompleteBox.DataContext = this;
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do it? 
Thank you in advance for the help!

Setting AutoComplete Box:

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="MyAutoCompleteBox" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

Code Behind:

```
public IList<string> Items
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Basic_ChildWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new List<string>();
        Items.Add(@"One");
        Items.Add(@"Two");
        Items.Add(@"Three");

        DataContext = this;
    }
```

Another datacontext in the same XAML page, AutoCompleteBox is inside that grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdBasic_ChildWindow_Right" Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource LabelsDataSource}}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question--what is "labelsDataSource"?

However, if what you have posted is all the code and there is nothing more to it, simply remove the datacontext/binding from the grid.  The grid does not need a datacontext set (it is simply a visual container--not data-related).

So change this:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdBasic_ChildWindow_Right" Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource LabelsDataSource}}">
```

To this:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdBasic_ChildWindow_Right" Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}">
```